# JavaScript remoting access parameter from one method into other

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript-remoting

I have some query on Javascript remote action, as i am not much aware of that concept. Pls help me out. I need to access a parameter of Remote Action method into another remote action method

```
Global class PolicyHolderDetails {
Public string Name{get;set;}
@RemoteAction
global static PageReference Save(String Name){
// some stuff.
return null;

}

@RemoteAction
 global static PageReference CheckInsurance(String insurance1){
  //i need access to Name parameter here..So that i can query..Is there any workaround for this..

}
```

Comment: static method can only access static variables

Comment: even though i declare the variable as static it is giving error.And first of all how should i access that in 2nd method.I tried calling Save method but there are more parameters other than Name so that wont be good idea..

Comment: You get it from the same place you got it when calling the first method

Comment: yes true but save method has around 10 parameters i need to call them with all..Is there any alternative??

Comment: May you add an inner class, then define many Attributes in it. Then you can pass a object as the parameter from visualforce page. Does it make sense?

Comment: I have already declared a class and added variables..Declaring inner class would be same i think..Because when i have to call that method with all parameters. Pls let me know if i am correct..Or provide some code for my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RemoteAction methods are static, and can't store Values. In remote action each transaction in Sales-force starts as a fresh slate, with nothing loaded in memory.

```
    Global class PolicyHolderDetails {

    public class Member {
        Public string Name{get;set;}
        // declare your Member here 
        Public Member(){}
    }

    @RemoteAction global static Member Save(String Name){
    // some stuff.
    Member member=new Member();
    member.Name= Name;
    return Member; // Store the Member in visual Force page.
    }

   // Resend member again from visual force Page to your Second remote action
    @RemoteAction global static PageReference CheckInsurance(String insurance1,Member member) {
      // Use Member here     
    }
```

**OR**

> **Session Class**

Another Alternative way is keep in server Cache. Way of doing this would be to use the [Platform Cache](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_features.htm) to store the data serverside. You can use a Session Cache to store the required data between Javascript Remoting calls and get it from that same cache when you need it.

Use the [Cache.Session](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_cache_Session.htm#apex_class_cache_Session) class to add, retrieve, and manage values in the session cache. The session cache is active as long as the user’s Salesforce session is valid (the user is logged in, and the session is not expired).

```
Global class PolicyHolderDetails {
 public class Member {
     Public string Name{get;set;}
     // declare your Member here 
     Public Member(){}
     }
@RemoteAction global static PageReference Save(String Name){
// some stuff.
 Member member=new Member();
 member.Name= Name;
 // Add Member to the cache.
 Cache.Session.put('member', member);
return null;  
}

@RemoteAction global static PageReference CheckInsurance(String insurance1){
   // Return cached value whose type is the inner class Member.
   Member member= (Member)Cache.Session.get('member');
}
```

Above session cache code only works if your created new **Platform Cache**. 
If you don't know how create a Platform Cache, Follow below link one by one

[First Follow this link to activate Request Trial Capacity](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/platform_cache/units/platform_cache_get_started)

[Second Follow this link to create new platform cache](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/platform_cache/units/platform_cache_use)

If your finished with above two step then click on **edit** on **platform cache which your newly created**, **Change trail value 0 to 5 in Session Cache Allocation and Org Cache Allocation** and save it.

Your done.

[How to use session cache](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_session_examples.htm)

Comment: I preferred to work on solution2 but there is an error..IN line Cache.session.put('member',Member);   Error:Member doesnot exist..

Comment: i have updated to  '  Cache.Session.put('member', member); ' may be the reason of case sensitive. can u try now .

Comment: Yes it is saving..But no data is getting created..`cache.Session.SessionCacheException: A default partition was not found`.This is the error i am getting bro

Comment: You have to create Platform Cache for that .

Comment: Follow the link https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/platform_cache/units/platform_cache_use

Comment: Above answer is working only , If you are created Platform Cache  in sales-force classic . let me know if don't know about that.

Comment: i have updated answer . if your not create platform cache follow the above step it is working .